# ReactJS: What is "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two method calls within a function called `loginUser()`. The first passes in userInfo and makes an API request, and then would like to execute the method to empty out the login text fields.

But I am getting the error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. What may be the issue?

Code:

```
  _loginUser() {
    this.props.loggingInUser(this.props.userInfo) //Would like to finish this first before moving onto calling this.props.emptyLoginTextFields()
    .then(() => { //Here is where the error is occurring
      this.props.emptyLoginTextFields()
    })
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like either `props` or `loggingInUser()` is undefined, can you try logging out `props` or debugging and ensuring that both are defined?

Comment: `loggingInUser` may not be returning anything...

Comment: how does your loggingInUser function look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the the promise manager like "axios" that returns the results ,

example : focus on

> "return axios.all"

```
 getPlayersInfo: function (players) {
    return axios.all(players.map((username) => {
        return getUserInfo(username)

    }))
        .then((info) => {
        return info.map((user) => {
            return user.data;
        });
    })
        .catch( function (err) {
        console.warn("error in getPlayerInfo",err);
    });
}
```

};

Comment: Thanks, I don't see "return" in other answer, but your answer save my day

Answer (score 2):

In my case was, that I didn't have an axios mock.

So I created `src/__mocks__/axios.js` with this code:

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: {} })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful to return the promise from the ajax call inside of the `loggingInUser` function. You probably don't have a return statement in it and the default return value is `undefined` for JS.

An example:

```
function loggingInUser(credentials) {
  return fetch('/foo/bar');
}
```